# VSTS build with multiple phases not respecting run conditions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a VSTS build setup with multiple agent phases, like this:

1. Agent 1 (Hosted by MS): Build a WAR file using Maven
2. Agent 2 (On-premise, private): Copy file to target VM behind firewall

On phase 2, I have the setting under Execution Plan for "Run this phase" set to "Only when all previous phases have succeeded." Per Microsoft's own documentation, this is what it should be set to if I want the phases to run sequentially. Parallelism on both phases is set to "None."

However, when I run the build, both phases run simultaneously. Why?

I don't want to just build the file on my on-premise agent because I don't want to install Maven there, for reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the previous phase is selected as the Dependency:
[image]

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: need this in TFS 2018 urgently!

Answer (score 0):

Agent Phases do not execute sequentially is mainly caused by the **Parallelism** option set as **Multi-configuration** or **Multi-agent** for an agent phase at least.

So please check all the agent phases, and make sure the Parallelism options as **None** for all agent phases.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I already have parallelism set to None for both phases. Added that detail to my question.